# SpringBoot property value inside annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations, placeholder

I have this annotation

```
@Listener(topics = "test")
```

that I want to relace with

```
@Listener(topics = "@Value(\"${topics}\")")
```

but I have this error

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'topics' in value "@Value("${topics}")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@Listener(topics = "${topics}")
```

and make sure the property actually exists.

(Not a 100% sure that it works, but somewhat confident ;) )